# What are good ways to omit the zero parts when formatting a time difference without manual checking?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I would like to display a complete sentence to user like this:

> The difference is 5 days, 3 hours, 16 minutes, 10 seconds, and 150 microseconds.

but exclude the zero terms.

For example: 91 days, 23:00:00 is printed as:

> The difference is 91 days and 23 hours.

The only way I could think of now is creating a bunch of `if` statements, as I posted below. I think this might be over-complicated and I was hoping that there was an easier way.

```
# prompts the user to enter the date following the order
d1 = input('Please enter the date time (YYYY-mm-dd hour:minute:second:microsecond): ')
m_d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')  # a datetime variable with the entered info
# prompts the user to enter another date following the order
d2 = input('Please enter the date time (YYYY-mm-dd hour:minute:second:microsecond): ')
m_d2 = datetime.strptime(d2, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')  # another datetime variable with the entered info
if m_d1 > m_d2:
    result_date = m_d1 - m_d2
else:
    result_date = m_d2 - m_d1

# total difference in number of days with fraction
difference_days = result_date.total_seconds() / timedelta(days=1).total_seconds()
# total difference in number of hours with fraction
difference_hours = result_date.total_seconds() / timedelta(hours=1).total_seconds()
# total difference in number of minutes with fraction
difference_minutes = result_date.total_seconds() / timedelta(minutes=1).total_seconds()
# total difference in number of seconds with fraction
difference_seconds = result_date.total_seconds()
# total difference in number of microseconds with fraction
difference_microseconds = result_date.total_seconds() / timedelta(microseconds=1).total_seconds()

# now, A complete sentence that breaks everything down to the
# correct units and excluding any 0s.
if difference_days.is_integer():
    print(f'The difference is {int(difference_days)} days.')
else:
    hours = (Decimal(difference_days) - int(difference_days)) * 24
    if difference_hours.is_integer():
        if difference_days > 1:
            print(f'The difference is {int(difference_days)} days and {int(hours)} hours.')
        else:
            print(f'The difference is {int(hours)} hours.')
    else:
        minutes = (hours - int(hours)) * 60
        if difference_minutes.is_integer():
            if difference_days < 1 and hours < 1:
                print(f'The difference is {int(minutes)} minutes.')
            elif difference_days > 1 and hours < 1:
                print(f'The difference is {int(difference_days)} days and {int(minutes)} minutes.')
            else:
                print(
                    f'The difference is {int(difference_days)} days, {int(hours)} hours, and {int(minutes)} minutes.')
        else:
            seconds = (minutes - int(minutes)) * 60
            if difference_seconds.is_integer():
                if difference_days < 1 and hours < 1 and minutes < 1:
                    print(f'The difference is {int(seconds)} seconds.')
                elif difference_days > 1 and hours < 1 and minutes < 1:
                    print(f'The difference is {int(difference_days)} days and {int(seconds)} seconds.')
                elif difference_days < 1 and hours > 1 and minutes < 1:
                    print(f'The difference is {int(hours)} hours and {int(seconds)} seconds.')
                else:
                    # ... other code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle. You don't have to rewrite the code for every unit of time, since it's the same:

```
non_zero_counts = {}
rest = result_date
for duration in ["days", "hours", "minutes", "seconds", "microseconds"]:
    td = timedelta(**{duration: 1})
    count = int(rest / td)
    rest = rest - count * td
    if count:
        non_zero_counts[duration] = count
```

The result is a dictionary:

```
non_zero_counts
Out[27]: {'days': 31, 'hours': 3, 'seconds': 34, 'microseconds': 50000}
```

I'll leave dealing with all the special cases for getting the language right up to you. Feel free to edit this answer to add your solution for forming the sentence itself.

**EDITS**

Forming the sentence:

```
if non_zero_counts:
    result = ', '.join(f'{value} {key}' for key, value in 
    non_zero_counts.items())
    print(f'The difference is {result}')
else:
    print('The two dates are the same.')
```

Input:

```
Please enter the date time (YYYY-mm-dd hour:minute:second:microsecond): 2022-08-04 15:30:20:12470
Please enter the date time (YYYY-mm-dd hour:minute:second:microsecond): 2022-09-08 12:44:33:12348
```

output:

```
The difference is 34 days, 21 hours, 14 minutes, 12 seconds, 998780 microseconds
```